# Rosdep pip instead of apt

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My node needs the Sympy Python package in version > 1.1.2 (otherwise [plane/ray intersections are wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879246/why-does-sympy-calculate-wrong-intersections-of-planes))

So far I had added `<depend>python-sympy</depend>` to my package.xml to have rosdep take care of the installation. However, `apt show python-sympy` shows version 0.7.6.1-1, which won't work. After I removed apt's package and did `pip install sympy`, I got version 1.3, which is good.

Can I have rosdep use pip instead of apt? Do I need to do a pull request to add `[python-sympy-pip]` in https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L3812 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304466/rosdep-pip-instead-of-apt/) by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We generally don't want rosdep rules that override the system version with a pip version.

On your own system you can create a custom rosdep rule that will replace the apt one with pip if you want. But in general for deployment and sharing you should plan to use the system version.

Please see discussion at: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/18840 for more context.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0